# How to manage session data in puppeteer web scraping

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to scrap data from this website immobilienscout24.de using puppeteer. I think it is required to keep session data to navigate different pages on the site. following is my code sometime some pages are not loaded and are detected my requests as robot requests.

Please see the code and help me with session management when web scraping using puppeteer.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
const storage = require('node-persist');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const pretty = require("pretty");


puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ["--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
    'ignoreHTTPSErrors': true,
    executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome',
    userDataDir: '/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default'
}).then(async browser => {
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    const baseURL = 'https://www.immobilienscout24.de'

    for(var p=1; p <= 10;  p++) {

     
    await page.goto("https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/neubauwohnung-mieten?pagenumber="+p,{
      waitUntil: "load"
    })

    const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
    const cookies = (await client.send('Network.getAllCookies')).cookies;

    await page.setCookie(...cookies);
    const localStorage = await page.evaluate(() => Object.assign({}, window.localStorage))

    const html = await page.content();
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    const tiles = $('.result-list__listing');

    

    tiles.map( async (i, item)   =>  {
      let link = $(item).find('a.result-list-entry__brand-title-container').attr('href');

      if (link.includes("expose")) {
        link = baseURL+link
      }
      console.log(link)
  });
    await page.waitForTimeout(10000)
    }
    await browser.close()

})
```

Comment: Well, you are writing a "robot" and making requests, so the site isn't wrong...

Comment: Thanks. it is correct. I just asked can I avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

You're making 10 request at the same time, because you're using a traditional loop:

```js
for(var p=1; p <= 10;  p++)
```

So the website properly had something like rate-limit to prevent ddos attack, that's why you're detected as bot.

With ES6, you can request 10 times but in a sequence like this:

```js
for (let p of [...Array(10).keys()] ){
    // execute your request here
}
```

Hope it help!